# Cannot use add method on JFrame in actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, addition, actionlistener

I am working on a school project and i am stuck. I am trying to create a panel (simple add methon on JFrame) in a listener after JMenuItem is clicked, but it doesn't work. If i try to create the panel outside the listener, it works just fine bud inside no. Panel is just extended JPanel, for now with nothing but in a future a plan to add there some features.

```
public class Gui implements GuiConstants, ActionListener {
    public static final int INIT_WIDTH = 1024;
    public static final int INIT_HEIGHT = 560;

    private JFrame frame;
    private KPanel KPanels[];
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public Gui() {
        KPanels = new KPanel[4];
        this.gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    }

    /**
     * Vytváří okno aplikace + inicializuje toolbar
     */
    public void createWindow() {
        frame = new JFrame(Strings.get("window-title"));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle(Strings.get("window-title"));

        frame.setJMenuBar(new KToolbar());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(Gui.INIT_WIDTH, Gui.INIT_HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        addToolbarListener(this);
        createPanel(1);
    }

    /**
     * Nastaví listener pro toolbar akce (kliknutí)
     * @param listener
     */
    public void addToolbarListener(ActionListener listener) {
        ((KToolbar) frame.getJMenuBar()).addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public void disableToolbarItem(int itemId) {
        ((KToolbar) frame.getJMenuBar()).disable(itemId);
    }

    public KPanel createPanel(int i) {
        return this.createPanel(i, null);
    }

    /**
     * Vytvoří i-tý panel v případě, že ještě neexistuje a i je v rozsahu 0-3 včetně
     * @param i
     * @return
     */
    public KPanel createPanel(int i, Color color){
        if (i > 3 || i < 0 || KPanels[i] != null) {
            return null;
        }

        this.KPanels[i] = new KPanel();
        if (color != null)
            this.KPanels[i].setBackground(color);
        this.gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.gbc.weightx = 1;
        this.gbc.weighty = 1;
        this.gbc.gridx = i % 2;
        this.gbc.gridy = i / 2;
        this.frame.add(this.KPanels[i], this.gbc);
        return this.KPanels[i];
    }

    /**
     * Odstraní t-tý panel v případě, že existuje a i je v rozsahu 0-3 včetně.
     * @param i
     * @return
     */
    public boolean removePanel(int i) {
        if (i > 3 || i < 0 || KPanels[i] == null) {
            return false;
        }

        this.frame.remove(this.KPanels[i]);
        this.KPanels[i] = null;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        createPanel(2, Color.CYAN);
    }
}

public class KMenuItem extends JMenuItem {
    private int id;

    KMenuItem(String name, int id) {
        super(name);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

public class KToolbar extends JMenuBar{
    ArrayList<KMenuItem> KMenuItems;

    KToolbar() {
        super();
        KMenuItems = new ArrayList<>();
        generateMenu();
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        for (KMenuItem item : KMenuItems) {
            item.addActionListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public void disable(int id) {
        for (KMenuItem mi : KMenuItems) {
            if (mi.getId() == id)
                mi.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void enable(int id) {
        for (KMenuItem mi : KMenuItems) {
            if (mi.getId() == id)
                mi.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private KMenuItem getLast() {
        return KMenuItems.get(KMenuItems.size() - 1);
    }

    private void generateMenu() {
        JMenu game = new JMenu(Strings.get("game"));
        KMenuItems.add(new KMenuItem(Strings.get("button-exit"), Gui.EXIT));
        game.add(getLast());

        JMenu newGame = new JMenu(Strings.get("button-new-game"));
        KMenuItems.add(new KMenuItem(Strings.get("button-new-game-current"), Gui.NEW_GAME_CURRENT));
        newGame.add(getLast());
        KMenuItems.add(new KMenuItem(Strings.get("button-new-game-panel"), Gui.NEW_GAME_PANEL));
        newGame.add(getLast());
        game.add(newGame);

        KMenuItems.add(new KMenuItem(Strings.get("button-save"), Gui.SAVE));
        game.add(getLast());
        KMenuItems.add(new KMenuItem(Strings.get("button-load"), Gui.LOAD));
        game.add(getLast());
        KMenuItems.add(new KMenuItem(Strings.get("button-abort-game"), Gui.ABORT_GAME));
        game.add(getLast());

        add(game);
    }

}

public class KPanel extends JPanel {
}

public interface GuiConstants {

    // System
    public static final int EXIT = 1;
    public static final int SAVE = 2;
    public static final int LOAD = 3;

    // Language
    public static final int CHANGE_LANG = 4;

    // Game
    public static final int NEW_GAME_PANEL = 5;
    public static final int NEW_GAME_CURRENT = 6;
    public static final int UNDO_GAME = 7;
    public static final int REDO_GAME = 8;
    public static final int ABORT_GAME = 9;
    public static final int HINT_GAME = 10;
}

public class Main {

    private Gui GUI;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }

    Main() {
        GUI = new Gui();
        GUI.createWindow();
    }
}
```

Edit: added complete example. There is no error log. I even checked object references and it all fits. It just doesn't add to the frame somehow a i dont know why.

Comment: Shouldn't the type be JMenuItem, not MenuItem?

Comment: No, its extended. MenuItem extends JMenuItem

Comment: And JToolBar, not ToolBar, and JPanel, not Panel? You seem to be mixing AWT and Swing willy-nilly.

Comment: Toolbar and Panel and MenuItem are my classes because i needed to add additional methods to them

Comment: Consider re-naming your classes so that they don't clash with other core Java classes. To best answer your question, you'll want to create and post a [mcve] so we can experience your problem first hand and also post the complete error message.

Comment: I added the whole code so you could see how it works. There is no error message, it just doesnt want to add component into the jframe inside the listener method actionPerformed.

Comment: *"I added the whole code.."* There is no `GuiConstants`, no import statements and no `main(String[])` method, so it's definitely not complete. OTOH don't post your complete code, but a [mcve] as suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels. I'm voting to close because of a lack of MCVE.

Comment: I just didn't think it would be necessary so i didn't put it here. But as you want, a added the main and constants.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it on my own. I forgot to call frame.revalidate() with each frame.add (in the createPanel method).